# Need help fixing my python code for text adventure game

Tags: python

I'm having trouble trying to get my code to run properly. When I run the code it works fine. Moving between rooms isn't an issue and when it comes to collecting the items there's no problem. The problem comes when I get to where the boss is and I enter the command in order to complete the game. However, it doesn't seem to work correctly. I've tried to rearrange it, but when I did, the problem then became that I couldn't collect the items but could then execute the command to fight the boss. Here is the code down below:

```
# data setup
rooms = {
    'Entry': {'name': 'Entry', 'go south': 'Great Hall'},
    'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'go north': 'Entry', 'go south': 'Bedroom',
                   'go east': 'Dining Room', 'go west': 'Cellar', 'item': 'helmet'},
    'Bedroom': {'name': 'Bedroom', 'go north': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'shield'},
    'Dining Room': {'name': 'Dining Room', 'go north': 'Kitchen', 'go south': 'Library',
                    'go west': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'boots'},
    'Kitchen': {'name': 'Kitchen', 'go south': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'wrist guard'},
    'Library': {'name': 'Library', 'go north': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'sword'},
    'Cellar': {'name': 'Cellar', 'go south': 'Dungeon', 'go east': 'Great Hall', 'item': 'breast plate'},
    'Dungeon': {'name': 'Dungeon', 'boss': 'sorcerer'}
}
directions = ['go north', 'go south', 'go east', 'go west']
current_room = rooms['Entry']
player_inv = []


  
# game instructions
def game_instruction():
    print('Welcome to the Text Adventure Game')
    print('Collect all 6 items before reaching the Dungeon in order to defeat the Sorcerer')
    print('Movement: go north, go south, go east, go west')
    print('Collecting Items: collect + "item name"')
    print('Fighting Boss: fight + "boss name"') 


    
# print game instruction
game_instruction()


# game loop
while True:
    # display current location
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room['name']))
    # display current inventory
    print('Inventory: {}'.format(player_inv))
    # get user input
    command = input('What do you want to do? ')
    # movement
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
            # display current room item
            if 'item' in current_room:
                print('You see a', current_room['item'] + '.')
            # display boss in Dungeon
            if 'boss' in current_room:
                print('You see the', current_room['boss'] + '.')
        # bad movement
        else:
            print("You can't go in that direction.")
    # quit game
    elif command == 'quit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    # collect items
    elif command == ('collect ' + current_room['item']):
        if 'item' in current_room:
            print(current_room['item'], 'collected.')
            player_inv.append(current_room['item'])
            del current_room['item']
        else:
            print('There are no items in this room.')
    # game win/lose conditions
    elif command == ('fight ' + current_room['boss']):
        if 'boss' in current_room:
            if len(player_inv) == 5:
                print('CONGRATULATIONS!\nYou have successfully defeated the Sorcerer.')
                break
            else:
                print('GAME OVER!\nYou failed to collect all the items need to defeat the Sorcerer.')
                break
    # bad command
    else:
        print('Invalid Command')
```

It gives me the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-----\Documents\TextBasedGame\TextBasedGame.py", line 59, in <module>
    elif command == ('collect ' + current_room['item']):
KeyError: 'item'
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Not every room has an item.  You can't check the item name unless you know the room has an item.  So, maybe `elif 'item' in current_room and command == 'collect '+current_room['item']:`

Comment: Not every room has an item. You must check that before `current_room['item']` is evaluated.

Comment: or use `current_room.get('item', None)` and later check for `None` (which would mean no item is in the room)`